# How to use SAP AIN (Asset Intelligence Network) APIs

Tags: rest, sap-business-technology-platform

I have a requirement wherein I need to call few SAP AIN (Asset Intelligence Network) APIs from a web page. I have created a web page where on a click of a button, I want to call SAP AIN API - lets say to get the count of equipment that I have setup in AIN.

The API URL Provided in the [SAP AIN](https://help.sap.com/doc/d2d73af931b14c7db6b4c216dca94c7c/1705/en-US/SAP_AIN_API_Tutorial.pdf) document is:

```
Application_URL/services/api/v1/equipment/$count
```

Lets say my AIN application URL is:

```
https://abcxyz.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/sites?hc_reset#Shell-home
```

I tried below approaches to form API URL:

`https://abcxyz.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/services/api/v1/equipment/$count`  -- Did not work

`https://abcxyz.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/sites/services/api/v1/equipment/$count` -- Did not work

`https://abcxyz.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/sites/services/api/v1/equipment/$count?content-type=application/json` -- Did not work

For all above URLs, I am getting `Internal 500` error.

- So what can be the way to form SAP AIN API URL? What am I doing wrong
  here?
- Also how do I pass basic authentication like username and password in
  HttpRequest in Javascript?

Any help would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working myself. I was using a wrong hostname of the API.

Answer (score 0):

The correct API endpoint for *equipment count* is: `application url` +  `/services/api/v1/` + `/equipment/$count`.

The *application URL* looks like: `https://ain.xyz.hana.ondemand.com/ain` (mind the included `/ain`) (see [SAP AIN API tutorial](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4d5ca1b8c320409d961551bc60695e25/latest/en-US)).

The full API endpoint would look like (replace `xyz` with your application): `https://ain.xyz.hana.ondemand.com/ain/services/api/v1/equipment/$count`.

See [SAP AIN API reference, version 1908](https://help.sap.com/doc/ad3f22daa99f4afc80f875f956776201/1908/en-US/equipment.html#equipment__count_get) for more information. You can test this also on the [SAP AIN equipment API](https://api.sap.com/api/EquipmentAPI/resource) of the [**SAP API Business Hub** for SAP AIN](https://api.sap.com/package/SAPAssetIntelligenceNetwork).